# Give permission to IIS user account for directory create inside the project's App_Data directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, iis-7

I have a situation please read on.

In order to let IIS worker process(process under which my web application is running)create  folder inside the App_data folder(in my website root) i have given the permission to the IIS user account (application pool identity).My worker process runs under this user account.

So when application runs the Application_Start method inside the Global.asax is called and the directory is created by the Application w/o problem.

Now the problem is when Every time the site is built and deployed,is the entire folder structure recreated in the webroot?I thought during build and deployment only the files inside the folder is replaced.Please clarify?

If it is so then i have to apply the permission to the App_data folder again in order to let the IIS worker process create the directory again via that IIS user account.

Please clarity the doubt.My problem is solved, if it is not required for me to set the permission again to the App_data everytime the site is build and deployed.

Thanks in advance S.

Answer (score 0):

Ive never tried but found this.He has provided a way to set permissions at deploy:

> http://sedodream.com/2011/11/08/SettingFolderPermissionsOnWebPublish.aspx